# How to exclude inactive categories/pages from generated google sitemap.xml?

Tags: magento-1.7, category, xml, sitemaps

Through **Catalog > Google sitemap** I have just generated a **sitemap.xml** file.

The file itself works perfect.
My problem though is, that the file **also contains inactive categories**.

I can't seem to find any options to exclude these inactive categories from my generated sitemap.xml file.

Do anyone know how this can be solved?

I am using Magento ver. 1.7.0.2

Answer (score 3):

Try this.

Edit the `app/design/frontend/your_package/your_theme/template/catalog/seo/tree.phtml` file in your theme. Add an if condition just after the foreach loop which checks for activeness of the `$_item`.

```
<?php $_items = $this->getCollection(); ?>
<?php if($_items->getSize()): ?>
    <ul class="sitemap">
        <?php foreach ($_items as $_item): ?>
          <?php if( $_item->is_active ) : ?> 
            <li class="level-<?php echo $this->getLevel($_item) ?>" <?php echo $this->getLevel($_item)?'style="padding-left:' . $this->getLevel($_item, 2) . '0px;"':'' ?>><a href="<?php echo $this->getItemUrl($_item) ?>"><?php echo $_item->name ?></a></li>
        <?php endif; ?> 
        <?php endforeach; ?>
    </ul>
<?php else: ?>
    <p class="note-msg">
        <?php echo $this->__('There are no %s available.', $this->getItemsTitle()); ?>
    </p>
<?php endif ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

On your frontend when you access this URL you will see only active categories

```
http://project_name/catalog/seo_sitemap/category
```

But if you look at the sitemap by accessing the below URL you will see disabled categories too

```
http://project_name/sitemap.xml
```

The reason is `**sitemap.xml**` is already generated when the category was active. You have to again generate a `sitemap.xml` file after disabling any category to reflect the active categories only.

Comment: Hey Vikran - thanks a lot for the suggestion. I did generate the sitemap.xml at a point where the categories were inactive and they still appear in the xml file :/ Actually the categories appearing in the XML that are inactive have been inactive 1 month prior to me generating the file.